# In Xcode 4.3, where do I put the additional tools?

Tags: xcode

I'm confused. I just downloaded 6 supplementary packages using `Xcode > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools...` and I thought the .dmg files would contain .pkg files, but instead they contain programs.  Where am I supposed to install these programs?

I suspect the answer might be "Anywhere you want." — But I don't like that idea. I want to put them in some standard or conventional location.

Oddly, there is no README file saying where these should go.

For now, I'm putting them in `/Applications/Xcode Tools`, but that seems kludgey.

Also odd:  There was a .dmg file for the the Command Line tools, which I installed, but that actually was a .pkg inside the .dmg, which is different from the other 6.  I'm not sure why Apple is providing a .dmg for the Command Line Tools when they are installable via `Xcode > Preferences... > Downloads > Components`. I think it's just confusing.

And finally: The "Audio Tools" image contains a directory called "CoreAudio", which contains a whole bunch of source code and include files. Where are these supposed to go? I don't want them under Applications.

The packaging of the supplemental tools seems a bit slapdash to me.

Comment: If they're just *.app folders then you can place them under /Applications and launch them with $open -a tool-name

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Find Xcode.app and open it by 'Show package content'
2. Drag and drop new development tool from downloaded .dmg to `/Applications` inside Xcode
3. Add yourself to 'Sharing & Permissions' of `/Resources` with rights to read/write
4. Repeat step 3 for file

   ```
    /Resources/IDEHelperApps.plist
   ```
5. Open file IDEHelperApps.plist in TextEdit.app
6. Add string with name of added tool to first array. For example:

   ```
   <string>Contents/Applications/PackageMaker.app</string>
   ```
7. Save `.plist` and restart Xcode.

Comment: Brilliant, brilliant, brilliant. This is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for. So is this typically where these things went before? (I never noticed in 4.2.) Do you know why Apple is making it such a pain in the butt for these in 4.3?

Comment: @ToddLehman they wanted to make Xcode not have to be a multi-gigabyte download for every update. So they split off all the tools you want. I think they make this so difficult because this is really a workaround. I would hope soon they do something more like this automatically

Comment: Will this remain in effect over an update?

Comment: Hopefully they will include them in the Downloads section of Preferences in the near future!

Comment: It seems to me that any new Xcode update might wipe out the additional tools copied into Xcode.app and then you'll have to download them again and reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

Put them wherever you want. Unix and Mac OS do not care where your executable files are.

Comment: Of course. :) But where are we *intended* to put them? Where makes the most sense? Where did they used to go with older versions?

Comment: /Applications is the major directory for *.app folders, any location within that folder or sub-directory of that folder is logical. The location where you have them now is perfectly expected. :-)

Comment: @ToddLehman I don't think theres an outright default location for them. They used to be under /Developer/Applications, so you could put them there again if you want. But I would recommend just placing them in /Applications.

Comment: There is nowhere you are "intended" to put them. There isn't anywhere that makes more sense than anywhere else. Put them wherever you want. Many people use `/Applications` or `~/Applications` or `/Developer/Applications` but there's no reason for that, it's a personal preference. With older versions they went somewhere in `/Developer/Applications`, but there is no reason to choose that over anywhere else. You can even leave them on the DMG if you want.

Comment: /Developer/* seems to have fallen out of use, XCode 4.3 even offers to delete the whole directory during installation.

Comment: Interesting. I'm on Xcode 4.2.1 and it installed itself in /Developer